# Selenium 2 Remote Web Driver: What happens when this code runs and I close eclipse?

Tags: java, selenium

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;


public class SimpleTest {
    private WebDriver driver = null;
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws MalformedURLException 
     */
    public void SimpleTest(){
        System.out.println("booting up");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

        try {
            WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new 

URL("http://myhubip:2341/wd/hub"), capability);
driver.get("http://myapp.com");
visitAllHundredLinks();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            recordtolog();
        }
    }



}
```

If I close eclipse while the test is running, will my test stop on the server or continue running until it finishes visiting all the links? Or is the entire SimpleTest serialized over the wire and run autonomously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will stop the execution. The commands are passed from eclipse and if that's going to be killed then your execution too will get killed. Having said that, if there is an inbuilt command in webdriver to visit all links (like `driver.visitAllLinks`) then it will execute provided the execution came to that command.